# Why is bootstrap not working in my laravel's home page?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, bootstrap-4

## What I've done so far

First of all I'm REALLY NEW at laravel. I'm watching a great tutorial on YouTube  and following most of the instructions. I uploaded the project to my domain, because I wanted to try out how the database connections worked in a production environment and using MySql (the guy uses sqlite in the video).
Even though I managed to make the project work as its supposed to, when I open up the page, it doesn't look alright, the smaller the screen is, the worst it looks, you can move sideways (it's hideous, really).

---

## It used to work fine

When I created a blank laravel project from hostinger, and I accesed it with my cellphone, for instance, it worked well, and by that I mean that the font that said "Laravel" had margins and everything looked centered and as one is supposed to see a bootstrapped page. After I created a project following the tutorial and uploaded it, the nightmare started.

---

## Showing you the code

The base laravel project says "Laravel" where my project says "gastiGram" (It's commented as "¡¡¡HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!!"); maybe with the less letters it works well on mobile (of course I'm kidding, I must have messed up somewhere). This is the code, guys and gals, so maybe you can help me out. Thanks.

***`welcome.blade.php`***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>gastiGram</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <style>
            html, body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #636b6f;
                font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
                font-weight: 200;
                height: 100vh;
                margin: 0;
            }

            .full-height {
                height: 100vh;
            }

            .flex-center {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            .position-ref {
                position: relative;
            }

            .top-right {
                position: absolute;
                right: 10px;
                top: 18px;
            }

            .content {
                text-align: center;
            }

            .title {
                font-size: 84px;
            }

            .links > a {
                color: #636b6f;
                padding: 0 25px;
                font-size: 13px;
                font-weight: 600;
                letter-spacing: .1rem;
                text-decoration: none;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }

            .m-b-md {
                margin-bottom: 30px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">

            @if (Route::has('login'))
                <div class="top-right links">
                    @auth
                        <a href="{{ url('/home') }}">Home</a>
                    @else
                        <a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a>

                        @if (Route::has('register'))
                            <a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a>
                        @endif
                    @endauth
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="content">
                <div class="title m-b-md">
                    gastiGram <!-- ¡¡¡HERE IS THE PROBLEM!!! -->
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-brand">
                    <div>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="links">
                    <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
                    <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
                    <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
                    <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
                    <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
                    <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
                    <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
                    <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: u need to include ` {{ asset("css/app.css") }}` and run `npm run dev`

Comment: Hi @KamleshPaul where/how should I include that? Note that hostinger doesn't support npm, so should I properly include that, run that npm command on my local environment and then upload it again? Thanks in advance.

Comment: run in local it will generate `public/css/app.css` that u need to upload to server and include that iin heading

Comment: I already did run that command at least twice in my local environment (I didn't know that's what created the file, I'm really new at laravel). The file already exists.

Comment: can you check that in your app.css file you have following lines in comments, `Bootstrap v4.5.2 (https://getbootstrap.com/)` version may differ

Comment: Hi @bhucho I'll check in the morning, it's already 4:15 here

Comment: also the blade file you have provided here does not have link for app.css in it

Comment: I added it as kamlesh suggested, and nothing changed. Why is it important to include that? Is the way he pointed out the correct one?

Comment: You need to add bootstrap cdn `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">` add all dependencies https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: @newbie can u check my answer now it will work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## As no one seemed to find an answer for me...

I tried what others said and my conclusion is that it wasn't a problem with bootstrap nor vue. I guess it was the fact that the classes `content` and `title m-b-md` didn't provide the desire responsiveness I expected from the text

```
 <div class="content">
    <div class="title m-b-md">
        gastiGram <!-- ¡¡¡HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM WAS!!! -->
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-brand">
        <div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="links">
        <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">Docs</a>
        <a href="https://laracasts.com">Laracasts</a>
        <a href="https://laravel-news.com">News</a>
        <a href="https://blog.laravel.com">Blog</a>
        <a href="https://nova.laravel.com">Nova</a>
        <a href="https://forge.laravel.com">Forge</a>
        <a href="https://vapor.laravel.com">Vapor</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/laravel/laravel">GitHub</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm willing to accept an answer that demonstrates that what I'm saying is wrong and I can apply other solution to my problem in this project.
Kamlesh Paul suggestions were useful to me... now I have a little bit of a better understanding on how laravel works; still it was insufficient since the font was collapsing sideways applying what he said would work, but didn't, so I just applied the style manually

```
<h1 style="font-size:20vw;">gastiGram</h1>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 <link href="{{asset('css/app.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I solved the problem placing this code in head section of welcome.blade.php page.